# Who is the real owner of a gTLD domain with Privacy Proxy?

Tags: domain-registrar, whois, privacy, ownership, private-registration

I recently registered a `.email` domain planning to make it my primary personal email for the time being, with my registrar I accepted a privacy service, my thought was they were going to mask my address and email (something like another `.it` domain I own where in public whois there is only name and surname), but instead they used a full privacy proxy, delegating the Registrant name to a Toronto Company.

While I have no fear losing the domain to that company, I want to be sure to being able to defend it against any opposition or dispute in the future.

So the main question is who is the legally owner of the domain? Me or the Privacy Proxy company?

Another question, my registrar has cheap price, but in fact turned out to be too cheap, while it's a well known 20 years company, they don't even offer nameserver change, nor I can change whois data on my own, as such I'm planning to transfer the domain to a better-feature registrar as soon as the 60 days lock since creation is expired, should I ask privacy service to be deactivated before transferring?

Comment: Technically no one ever owns any domain, they are leased with rights. Private proxies are not registrars. Registrars have both private and real information, you remain the lease holder of the domain.

Comment: About your second question: [Is it possible to transfer a domain without a “gap” in Whois privacy protection?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/30648/17633)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. According to ICANN,

   > A Proxy Service registers the domain name itself and licenses use of
   >   the domain name to its customer. The contact information of the
   >   service provider is displayed rather than the customer’s contact
   >   information. **The Proxy Service provider maintains all rights as a
   >   registrant (such as to manage, renew, transfer and delete the domain
   >   name), and assumes all responsibility for the domain name and its
   >   manner of use.**

   https://whois.icann.org/en/privacy-and-proxy-services
2. When you will move your domain name, you will get a new Whois record. Then, you will decide whether or not you want proxy service with the new company.